# JSON to HTML from url

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

I am currently trying to learn RESTful API's and implementing them into use case and one of the things I am trying to do is to load the url with the json payload from one server into a separate web server to display on a table the data. I am not too familiar with this so I am trying to find out the best way to do this.

I am using this API to post to a page which is domain.com/todos

https://github.com/corylanou/tns-restful-json-api

And then I am attempting to use this to print it out to a table
https://github.com/sam-suresh/JSON-URL-to-HTML-Table

but it doesn't look like it is working. I put it all into a single index file and it shows it hitting my api on the console but I am not showing any output in the table.

```
<html>
<table id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>due</th>
    </tr>

</table>

<style>
table {
  border: 2px solid #666;
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://my-website-domain.com/todos',
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
        drawTable(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.due + "</td>"));
    }

</script>
</html>
```

And this is what it shows on the /todos page

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Write presentation","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"id":2,"name":"Host meetup","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"id":3,"name":"New Todo","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
```

Comment: Can you share what do you receive in `data`? `console.log(data)` in `drawTable` function for example and provide an output

Comment: It looks like your todos JSON is missing a closing square bracket. Are there any errors being thrown in the console?

Comment: Your complete code is correct. May be the issue is in getting data, like the response which you shown above is not directly in data object. So once share or check data came from the ajax call.

Comment: Are you sure `data` of `success: function(data)` is a json object?

Comment: Response by qiAlex helped me figure it out. CORS wasn't enabled so the json was getting blocked. Enabled and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for all of the help. The issue was that the CORS policy wasn't enabled so the request was getting blocked. The fix was to simply enable CORS which was done in the handlers.go for this particular API by adding

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

The success function isn't passed the raw data. It's passed an object with a lot of different properties. Data is just one of them. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://my-website-domain.com/todos',
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(results) {
        drawTable(results.data);
    }
});
```

It's also possible I'm remembering this wrong. I'd put a `debugger` in your success function and see what it's actually getting passed, then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the JSON returned by the page /todos is not a valid JSON Array. Missing the

```
]
```

at the end.

So it would be:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Write presentation","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"id":2,"name":"Host meetup","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"id":3,"name":"New Todo","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}]
```

Here is a page to validate JSON data:
[Json Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you check API get json data, I copy your code and hash code json data and see it work.

```js
//$.ajax({
//    url: 'http://my-website-domain.com/todos',
//    type: "get",
//    dataType: "json",
//
//    success: function(data) {
//        drawTable(data);
//    }
//});
var data = [{"id":1,"name":"Write presentation","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"id":2,"name":"Host meetup","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},{"id":3,"name":"New Todo","completed":false,"due":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}];

 drawTable(data);

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.due + "</td>"));
    }
```

```html
<html>
<table id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>due</th>
    </tr>

</table>

<style>
table {
  border: 2px solid #666;
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make table of json data, you can use **`jQuery DataTables`**.

Here is the sample code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cjnIrxkIUi?indent=2'
    } );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```